# Simple HttpRequestMessage but not working

Tags: c#, rest, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I'm writing a simple dotnet core API, under search controller which like below :

```
[HttpGet("order")]    
public async Task <Order> SearchOrder(string ordername, int siteid) {
    return await service.getorder(ordername,siteid)
}
```

The swagger UI where the path `https://devehost/search/order` test pretty work, but when I use another client to call this api by below

```
client = new HttpClient {
    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://devehost")
};

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "Search/order")  {
    Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(
        new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> {
            new("ordername", "pizza-1"),
            new("siteid", "1"),
       })
};

var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

The status code always return bad request. But the postman is work, can I know the problem inside?

Thank you

Comment: You're doing a GET request...with a body? That doesn't seem right. Compare the actual request you're making with your app vs the request you're making with Postman. Tools like Wireshark and/or Fiddler can help you see the requests and compare them. From the API's perspective, it care whos calling it. If the request matches the shape it expects, it will give you the result you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a `GET` request, the parameters should be sent in the querystring, not the request body.

> [GET - HTTP | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET)
> **Note:** Sending body/payload in a `GET` request may cause some existing implementations to reject the request — while not prohibited by the specification, the semantics are undefined.

For .NET Core, you can use [the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.QueryHelpers` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities.queryhelpers?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to append the parameters to the URL:

```
Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new()
{
    ["ordername"] = "pizza-1",
    ["siteid"] = "1",
};

string url = QueryHelpers.AppendQueryString("Search/order", parameters);
using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
using var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```